# Wanting to change hover color on header links WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to change the [hover color](https://gyazo.com/36436241a7974a5a4c9f64277b5f3cc9) of the links within my header that I'm working on with WordPress and Elementor Page Builder.

[image]

I'm using two plugins for the header along with the page builder itself:

1. Header, Footer & Blocks for Elementor
2. NavMenu Addon For Elementor

I tried a bunch of CSS using inspect element and adding that into the custom CSS section on WordPress, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is now solved, the solution was adding !important after the color change, thankyou to the person who responded so fast!